# Undefined reference for function specialization in namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, g++, undefined-reference

I'm implementing a JSON archive system modelled after `boost::archive`. For each type you want to serialize, you define a non-intrusive function that accepts an archive and your object:

```cpp
// archive.hpp
#pragma once

namespace Archive {
    template <class A, class T>
    void serialize(A& a, T& value);
}

struct ArchiveOut {
    void add(const char* key, int& value) {}

    // ... Implementations for basic types ...

    template <class T>
    void add(const char* key, T& value) {
        ArchiveOut archive;
        Archive::serialize(archive, value);
    }
};
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "archive.hpp"

struct Child {
    int id;
};

struct Parent {
    int id;
    Child child;
};

template <class A>
void Archive::serialize(A& a, Parent& v) {
    a.add("id", v.id);
    a.add("child", v.child);
}

template <class A>
void Archive::serialize(A& a, Child& v) {
    a.add("id", v.id);
}

int main() {
    Parent parent;
    ArchiveOut archive;
    Archive::serialize(archive, parent);
}
```

Right now, the system works for complex nested types but only if `serialize` is in the global namespace. Once it's moved into the `Archive` namespace I get a linker error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DDP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMWEvEu.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN10ArchiveOut3addI5ChildEEvPKcRT_[_ZN10ArchiveOut3addI5ChildEEvPKcRT_]+0x20): undefined reference to `void Archive::serialize<ArchiveOut, Child>(ArchiveOut&, Child&)
```

I know my specializations have the right signature since they match boost's, but maybe my initial prototype is wrong? I've tried digging through the boost internals but can't find where the initial `serialize` prototype is. I've also checked other answers and all of them are related to specializations not matching the function signature or not placing it in the right namespace. Could I get an explanation for this linker behavior?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to partially specialize a function template. That's not actually possible.

Comment: I figured, so how did something like boost define the initial function prototype so it allows specializations like this? And why does it work in the global namespace?

Comment: See the Layer 2 comments in the [source](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp) "*note the usage of function overloading to compensate that C++ does not currently support Partial Template Specialization for function templates*". They use a 3rd `const unsigned int` argument to get this effect. There's even more stuff they do to handle compilers that do 2-phase lookup differently. I'm afraid there's quite a lot to figure out there before you can get your version to behave like the Boost one.

Answer (score 0):

You're using overloading where need partial specialization.

The problem is that a function can't be partial specialized.

Suggestion: use static functions inside partial specialized structs.

Something as follows (caution: code not tested)

```
// archive.hpp

namespace Archive {
    template <typename A, typename T>
    struct serial;

    template <class A, class T>
    void serialize(A& a, T& value)
     { serial<A, T>::func(a, value); }
}

// main.cpp
#include "archive.hpp"

// ...

namespace Archive {

   template <class A>
   struct serial<A, Parent>
    {
      static void func (A & a, Parent & v)
       {
         a.add("id", v.id);
         a.add("child", v.child);
       }
    };  

   template <class A>   
   struct serial<A, Child>
    {
      static void func (A & a, Child & v)
       { a.add("id", v.id); }
    };
 }
```